# Sort by value size()

Tags: groovy

I need to sort by `source` value size() descending:

```
def source = 
[(firstString): [3, 2, 1], 
(secondString): [3, 2, 1, 4],
(thirdString): [3]]

expected:

[(secondString): [3, 2, 1, 4],
(firstString): [3, 2, 1],
(thirdString): [3]]
```

I've tried to sort doing this:

```
source.sort { -it.value.size() }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to compare if sorted list matches expected one, do `expected == source.sort { -it.value.size() }` instead `expected = expected.sort { -it.value.size() }`. You sort expected list in your example and you use assign operator instead of equality.

Comment: @SzymonStephiank, I've edited the question. I need to sort `source` by value size. Sorting like I tried, simply does not work. I'm getting the same result :/

Comment: But `source.sort { -it.value.size() } == expected`. The code for sorting you have pasted already creates a sorted list like `[secondString:[3, 2, 1, 4], firstString:[3, 2, 1], thirdString:[3]]`.

Comment: Here, I'm getting an unordered list, as if `source` was never sorted.

Comment: `source.sort { -it.value.size() }` creates a new sorted list, it does not mutate the list you called sort on. That's why the result of `source.sort { -it.value.size() }` is equals to `expected` : `source.sort { -it.value.size() } == expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort that takes a Closure as an argument does not mutate the original Map. It only returns a new map, so you need to assign it (you can assign it to itself).

```
source = source.sort { -it.value.size() }
```

With [Collections](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html), there is another type of sort that takes a Boolean as well as a Closure. In this case, the Boolean indicates whether you want to mutate the original Collection or just return a new Collection.

```
a = [1,3,2]
a.sort (true) { it }
assert a = [1,2,3]
```

This doesn't apply to [Map](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html). So use the assignment syntax above.

Comment: That's it! Worked as expected. Thank you, @JeremyHunt

Answer (score 3):

The following is the working code for your expected result:

```
def source =  [
"(firstString)": [3, 2, 1],
"(secondString)": [3, 2, 1, 4],
"(thirdString)": [3]
]


def sortedResult  = source.sort { -it.value.size()}
println sortedResult
```

Working example here on groovy console : https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5104124974596096

Comment: Worked as well! Thank you, @Nitin!